# user crontabs don't work, only /etc/crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron, crontab, stdout

Hi when I use the command

```
crontab -e
```

to set up cron, the commands get triggered (according to syslog) but nothing happens. Also if I run sudo crontab -e.

The only way to actually get cron working is to manually etc

```
/etc/crontab
```

I'm confused, since syslog gives me the same output for both methods. Any ideas for tracing down this bug? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your crontab entry and if it's calling a script, post it, too. By the way, what you're experiencing would probably not be referred to as a "bug", technically speaking.

Comment: OS/distro/version might help too. Also check permissions of /usr/lib/cron/tabs or wherever your cron(8) looks for user tabs.

Comment: Also note that `/etc/crontab` and the `crontab -e` crontabs usually have different formats (with `/etc/crontab` having a user field that's not present in the per-user crontabs).

Comment: are you trying to run a command that needs to run with root permission?

Comment: i'm with this problem too...